# Why my answer was deleted, converted to comment, and then deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

I wonder why my answer to [Propositional logic: Finding a formula F with statement variables from truth table](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487683/propositional-logic-finding-a-formula-f-with-statement-variables-from-truth-tab) was deleted. Did I do anything wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the history, the answer was flagged multiple times as "not an answer", and the moderator in question judged this to be a correct evaluation of the situation and converted your answer into a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487683/propositional-logic-finding-a-formula-f-with-statement-variables-from-truth-tab#comment1049989_487683).

It's not that you did anything necessarily *wrong*, but in general, "link-only" answers which do not directly address the question asked probably should be left as comments.  (Though I guess you have yet to earn that [privilege](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).)

Comment: To say the same thing, in a different order: you can't comment, so you did the right thing by posting an answer, the community did the right thing by flagging your answer as "not an answer", and the moderator did the right thing by converting your answer to a comment. All is for the best in this best of all possible worlds.

Comment: I see. Thank you.